# how to Subscribe Error from IOT core on Server nodejs

Tags: node.js, mqtt

I have setup a server to listen from IOT core,
Use mqtt library, nest-mqtt supported in nodejs to establish connection between them.

I used the @Subscribe decorator to listen to topics from IOT Core.
With a large number of topics sent, there are times when Subscription is unstable, sometimes it is received and sometimes it is not received.

I want to set up a subscription error listener and is there a more stable way to fix the subscription error?

If you have used IOT core and encountered this problem, please share with me, thank you very much!

Lib:

```
import { IClientPublishOptions, Packet } from 'mqtt';
import { MqttService, Params, Payload, Subscribe } from 'nest-mqtt';
```

Subscribe decorator:

```
@Subscribe({ topic: MQTT_TOPIC.ON_LED, transform: (payload) => { return payload.toString() ? JSON.parse(payload.toString()) : {}; }, })
```